# A dynamic resize of this HTML from AJAX is making text unreadable. How do I "refresh" it?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am filling a pull-down list with data from an ajax call.  When the page first loads, the area looks like this:

[image]

After the pull-down list is filled via an Async call it looks like this mess:

[image]

If I click anywhere in the area it looks correct:

[image]

So - is there a way that I can tell the enclosing div or p to refresh so it does essentially the same thing after the select box is filled?

Thank you!

Comment: An example of your code would be nice...

Comment: Show your code and I will gladly answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give it a `min-width` in your css and set it to the width of the widest drop down item.

Comment: Ding-ding-ding...we have a winner! I think I need a break as it didn't even occur to me to format the control with css.  Thank you Interstellar!

Answer (score 1):

You have a mix of `block` and `inline` elements so they are overlapping.
You should make each piece of the form its own `block` element and then you can set properties like `width` or `min-width`.

CSS:

```
label { display: block; width: auto; float: left; }
input, select { display: block; min-width: 100px; float: left; }
```

HTML:

```
<label>Give</label> 
<input type="text" id="pts" />
<label>point to</label> 
<select id="person">
    // dynamically loaded
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Give Now">
```

Comment: Thanks @TerryR - this really helps flesh out my understanding.